# Convert postscript to jpeg

Tags: c#, jpeg, ghostscript, postscript

I have the ghostscript dll (gsdll32.dll) which I have wrapped into my c# application. I tried various way to convert postscript to jpeg but it's not happening. The code is as follows:

```
            PDFPrinter.WGhostScript gs = new PDFPrinter.WGhostScript();
            gs.AddParam("-sDEVICE=jpeg");
            gs.AddParam("-dJPEGQ=100");
            gs.AddParam("-dNOPAUSE");
            gs.AddParam("-dBATCH");
            gs.AddParam("-dSAFER");
            gs.AddParam("-r300");
            string outfile = txtOutFolderLoc.Text + txtFileName.Text + ".jpg";
            gs.AddParam(@"-sOutputFile=" + outfile);
            gs.AddParam(psFilePath);
            gs.Execute();
            Application.Exit();
```

What might be the reasons?

1. I have the postscript location at hand in the string "psFilePath".
2. "outfile" represents the location and file name of the output.

[I have used the same stuff and converted the postcript to PDF and PNG as following].

To PDF WORKED

```
            gs.AddParam("-dBATCH");
            gs.AddParam("-dNOPAUSE");
            gs.AddParam("-sDEVICE=pdfwrite");
            gs.AddParam("-sPAPERSIZE=a4");
            gs.AddParam("-sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray");
            gs.AddParam("-sPDFPassword=password");
            string outfile = txtOutFolderLoc.Text + txtFileName.Text + ".pdf";
            gs.AddParam(@"-sOutputFile=" + outfile);
            gs.AddParam(psFilePath);
            gs.Execute();
            Application.Exit();
```

TO PNG CODE:

```
            gs.AddParam("-dSAFER");
            gs.AddParam("-dBATCH");
            gs.AddParam("-dNOPAUSE");
            gs.AddParam("-sDEVICE=png16m");
            gs.AddParam("-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4");
            gs.AddParam(@"-sOutputFile=" + txtOutFolderLoc.Text + txtFileName.Text + "%i.png");
            gs.AddParam(psFilePath);
            gs.Execute();
            Application.Exit();
```

**EDIT I**
The postscript is being generated and the application continues till it exits. But no jpeg file is found.

The postscript is generated by a postscript printer provided with the ghostscript. Once this postscript is generated the control is transferred to the application that converts this PS.

Comment: can you elaborate on "its not happening." no file, empty file, wrong contents? and all you've changed between the working PDF and PNG versions is the -sDEVICE? could the postscript be missing `showpage`? that can lead to inconsistent results unless you run it through `ps2eps` first.

Comment: @luser droog: Thanks for you reply. I've edited the content & I've added the code to convert the PS to PDF and PNG. Both the functions are working fine. But the JPEG code seems like its not generating the output file.

Comment: That's about all I know from having used the commandline version for these types of conversions. But it's a much stronger, more answerable question now. Good job. +1 Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you very much @luser droog for your support

Comment: are you processing printer-driver output? that might have hardware  control code in it that is unsupported by pdf.  Some things to try: run gs from command line, so you will see any error messages; 2 test your program code with very clean/simple postscript code.

Comment: The command lines aren't the same, the first thing I woudl do is try to make the jepg and png commands the same, as far as possible. This includes making the order of the arguments the same since GS processes them in order. I would also drop any that were not required. So drop -dSAFER, remove the JPEGQ and the -r switches from the JPEG output and the -dGraphicsAlphaBits form the png output. You might also tell us which version of Ghostscript you are running. As george said, try running the commands from the shell, if that doesn't work then you know there's a problem.

Comment: Also, do you get anything returned on stderr and stdout ? Have you supplied callbacks for these functions from the DLL ? If not, add these as a first step. You really need the back channel available so that GS can *tell* you what's wrong.

Comment: I just noticed you don't have a `%i` in your jpg filename.

Comment: Even if %i is not given it gives the print. Creates one jpg file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the output with the following arguments:

```
            PDFPrinter.WGhostScript gs = new PDFPrinter.WGhostScript();
            gs.AddParam("-q");
            gs.AddParam("-dNOPAUSE");
            gs.AddParam("-dBATCH");
            gs.AddParam("-sDEVICE=jpeg");
            gs.AddParam(@"-sOutputFile=<full oytput file path>%i.jpg");
            gs.AddParam(<psFilePath>);
```

I had to add in the "-q" to get it done.

'*-q to prevent Ghostscript from writing messages to standard output which become mixed with the intended output stream.*'

Comment: glad you fixed it, but that doesn't actually make sense. Your output is to a file, not stdout.

Comment: @george: Hi there, I am not pretty sure about it, this just worked and the code that I've shown in the question just does not seems to work for some reason. Even though I've a working code I am still looking for a reason, "why the code in the question is not working".